# Can we check at a certain level of accuracy, whether a given charged body is uniformly charged throughout its volume?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, classical-electrodynamics

Assuming classical electrostatics hypothesis that charges are infinitely divisible, **can we check by any technique** at a certain level of accuracy, whether a given charged body is uniformly charged throughout its volume?

Comment: No, as lr1985 explains. The math is the same for determining the density distribution of an object from it's gravitational field. Gravitational surveys are used and do give some useful indications eg. of high density ore bodies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand your question, but my answer would be "no". Take a sphere of radius $R$ charged with a spherically-symmetric charge density $\rho(r)$. Outside of the sphere the electric field is given by

$$
\vec{E} = \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2} \hat{r}
$$

where $Q = 4 \pi \int_0^R \rho(r) r^2 dr$ is the total amount of charge contained within the sphere. **Any** charge distribution that is spherically symmetric and results in the same $Q$ will produce the same exact electric field at distances $r > R$, and hence the precise distance-dependence of $\rho(r)$ cannot be inferred from measuring $\vec{E}$ (or voltage) outside of the sphere.

For instance, all the following charge distributions will give raise to the same electric field outside of the sphere:

$$
\rho_0 = \frac{3 Q }{4 \pi R^3}
$$

$$
\rho_1(r) = \frac{Q}{\pi R^4} r
$$

$$
\rho_2(r) = \frac{5Q}{4 \pi R^5} r^2
$$

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean "Any such charge distribution ..." .

Comment: No, I mean any charge distribution such that its integral over all the body yields the same value of the charge. I have added some examples to get the point across. Let me know if it's more clear now!

Comment: Charge distributions that only depend on $r$ are good counterexamples, but not "Any charge distribution that results in the same $Q$". (Also, "isotropic" is not the right word).

Comment: @KeithMcClary thanks! I have edited the answer, substituting "isotropic" with "spherically-symmetric".